# C# Win Form App and FTP connection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ftp

I'm creating a Windows Form Application (C#) that connects to the FTP server, using Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Problem: *The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.*

Notes:

1. **no problems** connecting to the server **using primary FTP account**;
2. determined that the **problem is caused by @ symbol** in the ftpUser;
3. **tried replacing** ftpUser and ftpPW **with** the **values**;
4. host - GoDaddy - unlike primary account, all secondary FTP accounts need to have *@example.com* in their *username*;
5. **verified**, using FileZilla, that the **secondary account credentials** are correct;
6. in point 5), noticed in FileZilla log, Server does not support non-ASCII characters - even though it connects/transfers files without problems;

Below you will find the code that I'm using:

```
//Set Host, User and Password for the FTP;
string ftpHost = "ftp.example.com";
string ftpUser = "user@example.com";
string ftpPW = "passw0rd";

string ftpFullPath = @"ftp://" + ftpHost + ftpfilepath;

//Establish a connection to the server;
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpFullPath);
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPW);

ftp.KeepAlive = true;
ftp.UseBinary = true;
```

I'm wondering if the server is translating the proxy as username@host (i.e. user@example.com@ftp.example.com;

I apologize in advance if I made any mistakes in the lingo. I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: I think you are spot on.  Generally FTP sees @ as the start to a domain, i.e. user:password@ftpIP

Comment: You may be able to use:  string ftpUser = Uri.EscapeUriString("user@example.com")

Comment: Which library are you using for this task? I'm trying to connect via FTP on my project but I don't know if there is a predefined using System... or if I need to get an external library from NuGet

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the separation folder char (usually / or //) so the FTP server can index the file you want to get. Change this line and try with:

```
string ftpFullPath = @"ftp://" + ftpHost + "/" ftpfilepath;
```

Or

```
string ftpFullPath = @"ftp://" + ftpHost + "//" ftpfilepath;
```

Or (better way if available):

```
string ftpFullPath = @"ftp://" + Path.Combine(ftpHost, ftpfilepath);
```